# Spliting big XML file into small based on tag name

Tags: java, xml-parsing, sax

I have a requirement in which i will get a xml file & a tag name as input, I have to split the xml file using the given tag name using java.  Pls. suggest me s

INPUT:
XML FILE

```
  <note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
   </note>

  <book>
  <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
  <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
  <genre>Computer</genre>
  <price>44.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
  <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
  with XML.</description>
  </book>
 <book>
  <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
  <title>Midnight Rain</title>
  <genre>Fantasy</genre>
  <price>5.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
  <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
  an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
  of the world.</description>
```

TAG NAME: book

OUTPUT:

```
<book>
  <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
  <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
  <genre>Computer</genre>
  <price>44.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
  <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
  with XML.</description>
  </book>
 <book>
  <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
  <title>Midnight Rain</title>
  <genre>Fantasy</genre>
  <price>5.95</price>`enter code here`
  <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
  <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
  an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
  of the world.</description>
 </book>
```

Comment: University coursework ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the general algorithm is as follows:

- read the file into a buffer
- locate the first instance of your 
  tag
- keep reading lines until you find the last  tag
- output
  those lines

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done by `JSOUP`

[Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)

here is full working `example`

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        String path = Test.class.getResource("/test.txt").getPath();
        String string = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(path));

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(string);
        Elements elementsByTag = doc.getElementsByTag("book");
        System.out.println(elementsByTag);
    }

}
```

**test.txt**

```
 <note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
   </note>

  <book>
  <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
  <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
  <genre>Computer</genre>
  <price>44.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
  <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
  with XML.</description>
  </book>
 <book>
  <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
  <title>Midnight Rain</title>
  <genre>Fantasy</genre>
  <price>5.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
  <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
  an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
  of the world.</description>
  </book>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<book> 
 <author>
  Gambardella, Matthew
 </author> 
 <title>XML Developer's Guide</title> 
 <genre>
  Computer
 </genre> 
 <price>
  44.95
 </price> 
 <publish_date>
  2000-10-01
 </publish_date> 
 <description>
  An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.
 </description> 
</book>
<book> 
 <author>
  Ralls, Kim
 </author> 
 <title>Midnight Rain</title> 
 <genre>
  Fantasy
 </genre> 
 <price>
  5.95
 </price> 
 <publish_date>
  2000-12-16
 </publish_date> 
 <description>
  A former architect battles corporate zombies, an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen of the world.
 </description> 
</book>
```